# Set job scheduler when screen is on (device NOT idle)?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-background, android-jobscheduler, android-job

I know that the method `setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean requiresDeviceIdle)` makes the job run when the device to be in idle mode.

What I want is the opposite, I want the job to run when the device isn't in idle mode (screen is on and the user is using the phone) and I know that `setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)` doesn't do the job because saying "`false`" means that it isn't required so it'll run when it is idle and when it isn't.

Comment: I don't think that `JobScheduler` has an option for that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I must make an app that collects values from the different sensors while the screen is on and stores them in a file and when there is an internet connection ( second condition besides the screen being on) the file is sent to the server. All this must be done in the backgorund.

Comment: Why would any user want this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm assigned this project and I don't have much freedom to change the instructions but basically the purpose is to gather a huge amount of information in order for the artificial intelligence algorithms to work. It's a crowdsensing app so it makes sense that the user isn't benefitting from it but I did notice the battery drain that this is causing. I'm working on a way to reduce it but I still have no idea how to gather the maximum ata without consuming so much energy.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible via `JobScheduler`. If you wish trigger behavior based on the screen turning on, you must constantly be running (most likely as a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)) and programmatically register a `BroadcastReceiver`  listening for [`ACTION_SCREEN_ON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON).

Obviously this is memory intensive and a horrible idea for overall system health which is why it is not supported by `JobScheduler` (not mentioning the significant memory pressure already present during `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` due to it being one of the conditions of coming out of [Android 7.0's light doze](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#doze)).

Comment: thank you, so I must think of a different approach since this seems to be  battery draining.

Comment: I don't get it, wasn't Job Scheduler really designed to Solve the memory-intensive nature of (custom) Broadcast Listeners? Why then does it not provide a more memory-feasible solution to such problems